# Stop AsyncTask which is waiting for a synchronous method

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask

I want to stop/cancel the pendning AsyncTasks which is waiting for a synchronous method.

Below is my code:(Its starting all the 21 AsyncTasks. I want to stop in the middle, for example after 10 asynctasks completed. Can any one suggest a way for it?

```
 for(int i=0;i<21;i++){

   SafeAsyncTask<String, Void, LinkInfo[]> mGetLinkInfo = new SafeAsyncTask<String,Void,LinkInfo []>() {

                protected LinkInfo[] doInBackground(String... v) {
                    return downloadLinks(v[0]);
                }

                protected void onPostExecute(LinkInfo[] links) {


                }
            };

            mGetLinkInfo.safeExecute(i);
 }
   synchronized void downloadLinks(){
         //Lengthy process
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, with your code, you'll get 21 different AsyncTask, all playing at the same time in parallel. So your need to "stop after 10 asynctasks completed" does not make sense...

Maybe you'll want to have an unique asynctask, doing 21 differents parts of the job. Between each part, you then may insert a stop condition :

```
   SafeAsyncTask<Void, Void, LinkInfo[]> mGetLinkInfo = new SafeAsyncTask<Void,Void,LinkInfo []>() {

                protected LinkInfo[] doInBackground() {
                     LinkInfo[] infos = new LinkInfo[21]; // Is this what you want ?
                     for(int i=0;i<21;i++) {
                         // Do part i/21 of the job
                         infos[i] = downloadLinks(i);
                         if (getStopCondition()) break;
                         }
                     return infos;
                     }
            };

    mGetLinkInfo.safeExecute();
```

Comment: I have to run all the tasks in parallel.. That is the scenario. Do you have any solution for that?

Comment: Then it means that all steps are running. Then I think that you have to get an array of threads of all your 21 tasks, then send an interrupt to each one... But it means that the interruption must be handled by your `downloadLinks()` method.